# Is there a Redis-py function to get all secondary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, redis-py

I want to create a simple registration using a redis database. For this the user should not be able to register with an existing username/email. Say I use the username as the primary key, how would I check if any secondary values include the email they're trying to sign up with.

I've tried iterating through all primary keys and getting all the values but this seems too slow, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Scanning the keyspace isn't a viable runtime strategy. You'll need to "index" the values that you search for - see https://redis.io/topics/indexes for more information.